# "Indexed" checkbox for transient properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

In Core Data, transient properties are not stored in database. However there's *Indexed* checkbox for them in Xcode's model editor. What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute will be indexed, you can perform quicker searches on this and it is ordered after this.
nsfetchrequest will be much faster in combination with this.

Comment: `NSFetchRequest` can't use transient property (except for sectioning), no?